# How to use flume to read data from mysql?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase, flume

How to use flume to read continously from mysql to load to hbase?

I am familiar with sqoop but I need to continuously do it from a mysql source.
Is it required to have custom source to do this?

Comment: Almost the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548538/flume-to-migrate-data-from-mysql-to-hadoop

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop is good for bulk import from RDBMS to HDFS/Hive/HBase. If it's just one time import, it's very good, it does what it promises on paper. But the problem comes when you wanna have real-time incremental updates. Between two types of incremental updates Sqoop supports:

Append, this one allows you to re-run the sqoop job, and every new job starts where the last old job ends. eg. first sqoop job only imported row 0-100, then next job will start from 101 based on --last-value=100. But even if 0-100 got updated, Append mode won't cover them anymore.

last-modified, this one is even worse IMHO, it requires the source table has a timestamp field which indicates when the row gets last updated. Then based on the timestamp, it does the incremental updates import. If the source table doesn't have anything like that, this one is not useful.

I'd say, if you do have hands on your source db, you can go for the last-modified mode using Sqoop.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this, but I would write a script that takes your data from MySQL and generates an [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/) event for each.

You can then use the built-in Avro source to receive this data, sending it to the HDFS sink.